# Sharepoint 2010 Test Live setup

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I currently have a Sharpoint 2010 instance running on a server. I need to create a test environment to best mirror how live is set up. We will then be deploying changes to test then to live (as features). What's the best way to try and keep live and test in sync?

Comment: This *might* be an appropriate question for http://serverfault.com/ , if you can phrase it in a less general way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box support for synchronising content between Live and Test environments.

One viable way is to backup your Live content database(s) and restore them on Test environment **periodically**.

Also any customisations, solutions and features must be redeployed as part of each *synching* cycle.